# EC2 - possible to run Windows on an EC2 Linux instance?

Tags: windows, hosting, amazon-ec2, web-hosting

If you are handling all your own licensing(working under a BizSpark license), is it possible run Windows on an EC2 instance marked for Linux/Unix?

I am considering migrating a dedicated server I have to EC2 but was not able to find guidance on this.  I have been told that you get complete control over the instance to install whatever you like, but wanted to know if anyone else has tried this.  Thanks for the info!

Update:
Replacing a dedicated virtual with 512MB memory and 10GB storage.  Hosting mostly one-off sites and blog or three.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I remember that this was possible before Amazon supported Windows instances natively. You may want to check the links below to follow the discussions on the topic from the 2006-2008 era.

However you have to take into consideration that you will lose performance and you will complicate your setup significantly. The small Windows instance costs only about $18-$22 more per month compared to a small Linux instance, so I believe you have to evaluate if this gain will be of more value than the performance loss and setup complexity.

Related Links:

- [How To Forge: Running Windows on the Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud with Qemu and Linux](http://www.howtoforge.com/amazon_elastic_compute_cloud_qemu)
- [AWS Forums: QEMU / Windows Server 2003 / Fedora Core 6 Public AMI](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/thread.jspa?threadID=13446&tstart=0)
- [AWS Resources: Windows Server 2003 on Fedora Core 6 [Qemu] V.1.1](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=592&categoryID=101)

Comment: By losing performance, you mean having a server not specifically configured for Windows?  The price difference is significant and I'm trying to balance that.

Comment: You will be running a virtualization setup on top of your linux instance in order to launch Windows from inside it. That Windows virtual instance on top of the EC2 instance will be less performant than a native EC2 windows instance. So, if you take a small EC2 instance, you will not be comparing like-with-like in terms of performance, if you have to compare a native EC2 Windows instance with a linux instance running Windows virtualized inside it.

Answer (score 0):

It was possible before to bring your own License of Windows to Amazon under the [Windows License Mobility Pilot](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/windows-license-mobility-pilot/) but it seems to have been killed off... the API still exists though, so maybe its something they will bring later... I dont know the details, but i think you got the instance at the same price as you would a Linux instance, and no loss in performance either...